# SQL: loop through rows and update rows with highest value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table OD_REFERENCE (OD_COL_1 to 5)

REFERENCE has 5 columns where OD_COL_4 is equal to the order number (eg no. '12345') and OD_COL_5 has details of the order:

```
ROW  OD_COL_4  OD_COL_5 

1     12345       11

2     12345       11

3     12345         <---no number 

4     12345       99

5     12346       99

6     12347       99
```

Some order numbers have blanks (no value) and need to be manually updated to the highest number for that order column.

To find the order no's with blank details

```
SELECT DISTINCT OD_COL_4 FROM OD_REFERENCE

WHERE OD_COL_5 = ' '
```

Then I copy the order numbers from the columns to a notepad and run query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OD_COL_5 FROM OD_REFERENCE

WHERE OD_COL_4 = '--and i paste the order number in here'
```

Then I manually go through each order and update the values in all columns to the highest value in that column. So for order 12345 I set all fields to 99.

Is there a script I can use that will get all order numbers with blank details and correct them (all at once) with the highest value contained in that column?

Answer (score 1):

This should work in the SQL Server:

```
update a
    set OD_COL_5 = b.MaxOD_COL_5
from orders a
inner join(
            select OD_COL_4, max(OD_COL_5) as MaxOD_COL_5
            from orders
            where coalesce(OD_COL_5, '') <> ''
            group by OD_COL_4
          ) b
on a.OD_COL_4 = b.OD_COL_4  
where coalesce(OD_COL_5, '') = ''
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have never seen the Coalesce function before. I have a test db that im going to try these on...

Comment: COALESCE returns the 1st non NULL value from a list of values.  In this example, ISNULL would work exactly the same way.

Comment: In this example, coalesce(OD_COL_5, '') = '' is equivalent to (OD_COL_5 is null or OD_COL_5 = ''). I assume that OD_COL_5 can either be NULL or an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
update od_reference oref
set od_col_5 = (
    select max(od_col_5)
    from od_reference
    where od_col_4 = oref.od_col_4
    ) s
where od_col_5 = ' '
```

Comment: I am not sure if you can use the same table column as reference in DML type queries.

Comment: ~Bhrugesh you certainly can, that's what the aliasing of od_reference is on the first line.  I just wouldn't use an SQL reserver word **or** for the alias name.

Comment: @MarlinPierce Sure. Corrected.

Comment: so would i basically run this as is or would i need any direct input? Oh and thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are after, this should work in SqlServer
Update o Set o.od_col5 = n.highvalue From od_reference o  Join (select distinct t1.od_col4, (select max(t2.od_col5) from od_reference t2 where t2.od_col4 = t1.od_col4) as highvalue From od_reference t1 Where t1.od_col5 = '') as n On o.od_col4 = n.odcol4 Where o.od_col5 = ''